# Convert array of JSON String to array of object in Python

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, deserialization

I having array of JSON string, I need to convert it as array of object (i.e., convert the JSON to respective object) without a for loop.

Source Code: (Input data)

```
data = ['[1,2,3]', '[4,5,6]', '[7,8,9]']
```

Required Output:

```
[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

I already using the following solution

```
import json

data = ['[1,2,3]', '[4,5,6]', '[7,8,9]']
output = []
for item in data:
    output.append(json.loads(item))
```

Currently I'm having a very large number of JSON strings (approx 100K records) and moreover each JSON String array internally contains the record approx 50K. While on execution it takes more than 3GB of RAM for processing.

> **Note**: Implicitly the output is a 2-dim array `[][]`. 1st dimension is
>   approx 100K records 2nd dimension contains approx 50K records. Totally
>   100K * 50K items.

While on conversion it takes more time to convert the JSON (for the above approach). Kindly assist me the idea to convert the JSON string without a for loop.

Comment: Getting rid of the loop won't make a noticeable difference.

Comment: Consider `multiprocessing`

Comment: um... `data` isn't in JSON format?

Comment: @Anthony - the variable `data` contains an array of string (i.e., string is nothing but a JSON formatted string)

Comment: no, you're wrong, the string is not formatted as JSON... JSON is formatted as key/value pairs like so... `"key" : "value"`

Comment: @Anthony please re-read the json format documentation. `"[1, 2, 3]"` is the (perfectly valid) json representation of a list of integers.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers which documentation, [this documentation?](https://json.org/) can you link me to the specific part that explains that?!

Comment: @Anthony : "JSON is built on two structures:
A collection of name/value pairs (...)
An ordered list of values. In most languages, this is realized as an array, vector, list, or sequence."

Comment: @Anthony it's indeed considered bad practice to not wrap the content in an object (mostly because of a security issue in Javascript that allow to inject code when deserialzing a json array), but it's nonetheless technically correct - and as a matter of fact, the `json` module does accept a json list.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers interesting. you learn something new everyday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now solution looks wired but this works and will be useful for you in optimization. Convert the complete list into str then remove all `'` single commas with str function and the apply json loads, hurray this has got worked for me.

```
data = ['[1,2,3]', '[4,5,6]', '[7,8,9]']
r = str(data).replace("'",'')

import json
data = json.loads(r)
```

now your `data` will be of list of list without looping. You can achieve this.

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

ujson could make your code faster

```
import time
import json
import ujson

a_list = list(range(5000))
data = [str(a_list)] * 10000

s = time.time()

output = []
for item in data:
    output.append(json.loads(item))

print("json : %s" % (time.time()-s))

s = time.time()

output = []
for item in data:
    output.append(ujson.loads(item))

print("ujson : %s" % (time.time()-s))
```

On my PC...

```
json : 10.048374891281128
ujson : 6.533677577972412
```